# Eliminating Scrapy warning for several spiders with the same name

Tags: scrapy

I'm getting a warning from Scrapy that I have multiple spiders with the same name. As the terminal output below explains, I have no idea why.

```
(env) MacBook-Air:scrapy_project username$ find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;

(env) MacBook-Air:scrapy_project username$ grep -rl name_of_spider .
./bot/spiders/vendors/name_of_spider.py

(env) MacBook-Air:scrapy_project username$ scrapy crawl name_of_spider
/Users/username/scrapy_project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py:36: UserWarning: There are several spiders with the same name:

  NameOfSpiderSpider named 'name_of_spider' (in bot.spiders.vendors.name_of_spider)
  NameOfSpiderSpider named 'name_of_spider' (in bot.spiders.vendors.name_of_spider)

  This can cause unexpected behavior.
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

Comment: Had the same once when I made a subclass without putting a spider_name in the subclass

Comment: @WimHermans I believe it's just `name` but I do have that set.

Comment: just name indeed. can you copy-paste the relevant parts of your spider?

Comment: I've stripped it down to just 2 lines in an effort to debug:
```
class VendorSpider(ProductSpider):
    name = 'vendor_spider'
```

Comment: It's inheriting from ProductSpider, is there a name set for that class? and is there any class that inherits from VendorSpider?

Comment: @WimHermans `ProductSpider` inherits from `CrawlSpider` and has its name set via the class variable `name = 'product_spider'`.

Comment: Did you look for “name_of_spider” in that file, see if it appears in more than one class? Otherwise, can you write a reproducible example with minimal code?

Comment: Per the grep in my question, yes, I've looked everywhere. I created a new spider and am now getting the warning for both spiders.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's your case, but maybe it will help someone else, as I googled the warning message and didn't find much relevant help.

**tl;dr**: *check the paths in `SPIDER_MODULES` in `settings.py`, if there are subfolders of `spiders` in the list, these subfoldered spiders will be discovered multiple times by a scrapy loader.*

**My case**: I have multiple spiders in the `spiders/` directory and then a bunch of other spiders in `spiders/grouped/` subfolder, that are inherited from abstract/base spider (in `spiders/grouped/__init__.py`).

```sh
spiders
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── __init__.py
└── grouped
    ├── c.py
    ├── d.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I used to think I need to specify all subfolders in `SPIDER_MODULES` in `settings.py`, like that:

```py
SPIDER_MODULES = ["my_scraper.spiders", "my_scraper.spiders.grouped"]
```

but loader finds all spiders recursively, so correct way would be just:

```py
SPIDER_MODULES = ["my_scraper.spiders"]
```